# Is there any way to get the Nth key or value of an ordered hash other than converting it to an array?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 1.9.x I have a hash that maintains its order

```
hsh = {9=>2, 8=>3, 5=>2, 4=>2, 2=>1}
```

Is there a way to get say the key of the third element other than this:

```
hsh.to_a[2][0]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using [`Hash#keys`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000743) and [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000744):

```
thirdKey = hsh.keys[2]
thirdValue = hsh.values[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use hash instead of an array? The array fits perfect for ordered collections.

```
array = [[9, 2], [8, 3], [5, 2], [4, 2], [2, 1]]
array.each { |pair| puts pair.first }
```

Sorting of arrays is very simple, ultimately.

```
disordered_array = [[4,2], [9,2], [8,3], [2,1], [5,2]] 
disordered_array.sort { |a,b| b <=> a }
=> [[9, 2], [8, 3], [5, 2], [4, 2], [2, 1]]
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm, actually you're right.  I'm using the Multimap, Multiset gem for frequency counts, and maybe I should fork it and convert it to use arrays.  There'd definitely be alot of performance gains.